# Database with ID <guid> was not found in database collection

Tags: administration, 2019

The error listed in the title is repeatedly showing up in the ULS logs, with four different GUIDs. After failing to find any database with a matching guid via get-spdatabase, it was noticed that the guids listed are actually the guids for the servers in the farm:

```
get-spserver | select address, id
```

The above command returns the GUIDs being reported in the log.

More details from the log: the name indicates that perhaps this has to do with a feature activation, as the name column has: "timer job job-app-install-queue", and "timer job job-async-feature-activation2"

Any suggestions on what is causing this or how to track this down further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error you can ignore, likely a bug. It appears to impact any job that uses the `SPWorkItemJobDefinition` class.

Comment: Thanks Trevor!!